# How to pass navigation props to "createStackNavigator" to use default header with animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have been working over the last few days to add an animated header to my screens. I have succeeded in this however I would now like to apply this as my header by default rather then copying and pasting the code into all screens I wish to use it. At the moment the animated header is implemented in the screen as follows:

To render the header:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        header: () => {
            return (
                <SafeAreaView style={{
                    height: 0,
                    overflow: 'visible',
                }}>
                    <Animated.View style={{height: 80, width: 80,
                        transform: [ {translateY: navigation.getParam('headerScrollY', 0)}]
                    }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 20}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                            <Icon.Ionicons  style={{color: '#ffffff', width: 50, height: 50}} name={'ios-arrow-round-back'} size={50} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </Animated.View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            )
        }
    }
};
```

To setup the state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        headerScrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
}
```

To set the animation interpolation
 and pass value to navigation props (this is what I am going to have to access later when rendering the header)

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        headerScrollY: this.state.headerScrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 80],
            outputRange: [0, -80],
        })
    });
}
```

Main render method with "scrollView" calling "onScroll" event to pick up scrolling action

```
render() {
    return (
            <ScrollView
                style={Styles.wholePageContainer}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                onScroll={Animated.event( [{nativeEvent:{contentOffset: {y: this.state.headerScrollY}}}])}
            >
                ...
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
```

---

To set the default header I must set the "header" value of "defaultNavigationOptions" when I use "createStackNavigator". I am able to use this to create a simple defaultHeader in red with height of 100 (code and image below):

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Category: CategoryScreen,
    Venue: VenueScreen,
    Activity: ActivityScreen,
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        header: <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ff0000', height: 100}} />
        ,
    },
});
```

[Simulator demonstrating application of simple default header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTZbJ.png)

Unfortunately for my animated header I require the "navigation" prop as this is used to store the animation values. I have tried many approaches into passing this to where I need the values and was wondering if anyone knew how to do this or if it is even possible or if anyone had any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried this:

`defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  header: <YourHeader navigation={navigation} />
})`

Comment: Fantastic, it worked! Thank you very much. I had tried many similar variations however due to the documentation saying the header must be a function I always made that a function where I tried to get the navigation props where I should have been 1 stage up the link as you suggested. I will post the working code below.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Hend El-Sahli I have now got the code to work as intended. The result (for future reference for others) is as before however removing the header definitions in the navigation options for each screen and the "createStackNavigator" call is as follows:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Category: CategoryScreen,
    Venue: VenueScreen,
    Activity: ActivityScreen,
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header:
            <SafeAreaView style={{
                height: 0,
                overflow: 'visible',
            }}>
                <Animated.View style={{height: 80, width: 80,
                    transform: [ {translateY: navigation.getParam('headerScrollY', 0)}]
                }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{padding: 20}} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                        <Icon.Ionicons  style={{color: '#ffffff', width: 50, height: 50}} name={'ios-arrow-round-back'} size={50} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Animated.View>
            </SafeAreaView>
    }),
});
```

Comment: My (dumb) mistake was that I was using `headerLeft: ({navigation}) => `, which **doesn't exist**! Using `defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) =>` solved the problem! Thank You!